# Apache ignite startup failure

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Apache ignite .net core server node fails to start with the below error, any idea what could be the reason?

```
Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Java exception occurred [class=java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, message=]
  Source=Apache.Ignite.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Ignition.Start(IgniteConfiguration cfg)
   at IgniteShared.Cache.CacheService.<Start>b__3_0() in C:\Users\user\IgnitePoc\IgniteShared\Cache.cs

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
JavaException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.memory.PlatformAbstractMemory.<clinit>(PlatformAbstractMemory.java:27)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformAbstractBootstrap.init(PlatformAbstractBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.PlatformIgnition.start(PlatformIgnition.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.address field is unavailable.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1570)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1557)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.bufferAddressOffset(GridUnsafe.java:1557)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe.<clinit>(GridUnsafe.java:109)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field long java.nio.Buffer.address accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.nio" to unnamed module @69663380
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.GridUnsafe$2.run(GridUnsafe.java:1562)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: What is your Java version?

Comment: I'm on jdk-17.0.2 and jre1.8.0_321

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Ignite requires Java 8 or Java 11.
Java 17 is not yet supported.

https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/dotnet

(update: Java 17 support is coming soon: [IGNITE-16622](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-16622))

Comment: Added JDK 17 support in [2.13.0](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.13.0/release_notes.html)

Comment: You need to add few JVM args. Follow this: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/setup#running-ignite-with-java-11-or-later

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue when launching Ignite from a java application (the start-up script `ignite.sh` wasn't used); with `Java 17.0.3` and `Ignite 2.13.0`. At that time, the documentation only described the required JVM options for running Ignite with Java 11 ([Running Ignite with Java 11](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java#running-ignite-with-java-11)). So, I found the necessary JVM options for running Ignite with Java 17 in the source code ([jvmdefaults.sh](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/2.13.0/bin/include/jvmdefaults.sh)).